# Finding the minimum and maximum values of a date range in sql

Tags: mysql, date

I have inherited a database with a column called 'dateRange'. I've been asked to find the earliest/starting and the latest/ending dates. Here is how the original data column looks like:

[dateRange Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccAB6.png)

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT
@EarliestDate := SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',1) as StartingDate,
@LatestDate := SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',-1) as EndingDate,
MIN(@EarliestDate) as LowRange,
MAX(@LatestDate ) as HighRange
FROM `dateRangeTable`;
```

[Output from Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcFTD.png)

The output shows two columns with two values: 1) EarliestDay (01/01) and 2) LatestDay(01/31/15).

Obviously, this is not correct because the latest date should be 12/31/15 and not 01/31/2015.

What am I doing wrong? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `@EarliestDate` and `@LatestDate` are stored as *strings*, not *dates*.
So MySQL is sorting them as strings, which means that MAX and MIN give you first and last, alphabetically.

To have MySQL sort them correctly, you need to convert the string to a `DATE`, and then MAX and MIN will return the earliest and latest date.

Read more on how to convert text to date [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

**EDIT**

OK - let's do it step by step.
First step would be to split each record 'from' and 'to' dates, still leaving them as strings.

Note that the 'from' date is missing the year, so we need to grab the year for this one from the 'to' date.

Here's a query that does that:

```
SELECT dateRange, 
CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',1), '/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'/',-1)) AS from_date, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',-1) AS to_date
FROM dateRangeTable;
```

Result:

[image]

Next step - convert those strings to dates. Well, that's just wrapping them up with the STR_TO_DATE function exactly as you did:

```
SELECT dateRange, 
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',1), '/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'/',-1)), '%m/%d/%y') AS from_date, 
STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',-1), '%m/%d/%y') AS to_date
FROM dateRangeTable;
```

Result:

[image]

Last step - find the earliest 'from' date and latest 'to' date:

```
SELECT 
MIN(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',1), '/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'/',-1)), '%m/%d/%y')) AS min_from_date, 
MAX(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',-1), '%m/%d/%y')) AS max_to_date
FROM dateRangeTable;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response and direction, Galz. I'm going to try it out. I will update the this post soon after.

Comment: Galz, After a few trials Im still having trouble. Here is what I've done: 1) commented Min and Max and added STR_TO_DATE function. Unfortunately Im getting NULLS. Here is my code: SELECT
      @EarliestDate := SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',1) as StartingDate,
      @LatestDate := SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dateRange`,'-',-1) as EndingDate,
      #MIN(@EarliestDate) as LowRange,
      #MAX(@LatestDate ) as HighRange,
      STR_TO_DATE(‘EndingDate', ‘%m/%d/%y’) AS STR2DATE 
   FROM 
      `movieTable`

Comment: @microhtml - see the edit in the answer. Hope that helps

Comment: this worked very nicely! Thanks a million not only for your solution but for providing step by step instructions. Makes it so easy to understand not only the solution to this problem but also the approach one needs to take with other problems.

Comment: @microhtml - if the answer was helpful, make sure to accept it :)

Comment: Just did. Thank you!